# What is the difference between Trust and Faith?

Tags: differences, nouns

They seem to be similar. What is the difference?

Comment: The words have a large overlap in meaning/s, but the flavours Extragorey mentions are relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I would posit that trust is the rapport you build with someone based on past experience, whereas faith is an expectation you hold based on a belief in their beneficence.

**References:**

Dictionary.com defines [trust](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/trust?s=t) as follows: "reliance on the integrity, strength, ability, surety, etc., of a person or thing; confidence" - and implicitly reliance requires a prior baseline to work from.

Meanwhile [faith](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/faith?s=t) has the definition: "belief that is not based on proof."

Comment: 'Positing' is expressing an opinion. The site expects substantial answers supported by citations.

Comment: My apologies. Just trying to help.

Comment: Why not edit and add some references ?

Comment: I could add citations, but it would probably be a strong case of confirmation bias if I did that. Most definitions seem to point to them being synonymous, so to fit my above observation I'd be searching off the beaten path.

Comment: Nevertheless, I've added some definitions for conformity's sake.